# Find two coins of weight a, among n coins, where n-2 coins are coins of weight b

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

**Task:** Among the n coins there are exactly 2 coins of weight a, and exactly $n − 2$ coins of weight $b, a < b$.
It is allowed to compare the weight of any two coins in one turn (there are three comparison results: lighter, heavier, of the same
weight). Purpose: to determine the weight of each coin. Prove that there is such a constant $C$ that
at least $\frac{2n}{3} − C$ comparisons are necessary.

**Some thinkings:** Not sure where to begin. As far as I understand, in this task it is necessary to prove that in less than $\frac{2n}{3}$ comparisons it is impossible to determine the weight of each coin.

**UPD:** In the comments, people left really good advice on solving this task, but it is unclear how to link this to the constant C. It is clear that at best it is possible to determine the weight of all coins in 2 comparisons, and in $\frac{2n}{3}$ comparisons in the worst case. But how exactly to relate this to the constant C is not entirely clear to me

Comment: I assume that this means there is no strategy which is guaranteed to work every time that uses fewer than $2n/3-C$ comparisons (that is, the worst case scenario is at least $2n/3$). Best case scenario is two comparisons.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said $2n/3-C$, not $2n/3$.

Comment: Hint: Consider the simpler case where there is just one lighter coin. In any comparison between two coins, either you would have found the lighter coin or would have been able to eliminate 2 heavy coins. This implies you will need at least $n/2$ comparisons to eliminate all heavy coins. In this scenario, you can analogously show that in 2 comparisons, you can eliminate at most 3 coins, which would give you the answer.

Comment: And what about the constant C, how will it relate to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sudeep has given a nice hint in the comments. First observe that for $n=3$, you require 2 moves in the worst case, so $C\le 0$. By "determine" I mean deduce the type of coin.

Next, note that we can divide the $n$ coins into $n/3$ parts or $\lfloor n/3\rfloor+1$ parts depending on $n \text{ mod } 3$. In the second case, the last part contains one or two coins, while all other parts contain three coins. It takes two moves to completely determine a triplet of coins (can you see why?).

So, for $n=3k$, you require $2n/3$ moves, for $n=3k+1$, the last part has length $1$ and is completely determined by the results of the previous part, so you only need to determine the first $k$ parts. For $n = 3k+2$, you need to determine all the $k+1$ parts, but for the last part, you only need one move. Note that $\lfloor 2n/3 \rfloor = 2k+1$, so we're good.